# The application crashes with foreground service on Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, foreground

There is a foreground service code that works great on Android 8.1. In Android 7 the application crashes after a splash screen. How to change my code for Android 7 (API 24) and for Android 6 (API 23)? Delphi 10.3
Thanks.

```
  function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
var
  ServiceChannel: JNotificationChannel;
  NotificationManager: JNotificationManager;
  Obj: JObject;
  NewIntent: JIntent;
  ncb: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
  ntf: JNotification;
  PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
begin

  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY;

   ServiceChannel := TJNotificationChannel.JavaClass.init(
      StringtoJString('com.radio.one'),
      StrToJCharSequence('Public radio Channel'),
      TJNotificationManager.JavaClass.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
      );
    Obj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(
      TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationManager := TJNotificationManager.Wrap(Obj);
    NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(ServiceChannel);
    PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      JavaService.getApplicationContext, 0, Intent, 0
      );
    ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(
      TAndroidHelper.Context,
      StringToJString('com.radio.one')
      );
    ncb.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('PublicRadio'));
    // ncb.setTicker(StrToJCharSequence('Communications Service'));
    ncb.setSmallIcon(JavaService.getApplicationInfo.icon);
    ncb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent);
    ncb.setOngoing(True);
    ntf := ncb.build;
    JavaService.startForeground(StartId, ntf);

end;
```

Comment: I would suggest checking return values for failure before using the results.  One may be failing and it's pretty easy to check against nil before trying to use/reference it latter.

Comment: Hi Lena. I don't know Delphi, but just to mention startForegroundService was only added in Android 8 / API 26. Prior to that startService needed to be called which is normally handled in Java for example by calling ContextCompat.startForegroundService. Not sure if this is related or not. Kind Regards.

Comment: _How to change my code for Android 7 (API 24) and for Android 6 (API 23)?_ That's likely off-topic. Do you have a *specific*, technical question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use:

```
if TOSVersion.Check(8) then
begin
  // Your code, beginning with creation of the notification channel, and ending with the call to startForeground, goes here
end;
```

i.e. you don't need to call any of that for versions below 8.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I fix.

```
function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
var
  //Android 8.1
  ServiceChannel: JNotificationChannel;
  NotificationManager: JNotificationManager;
  Obj: JObject;
  NewIntent: JIntent;
  ncb: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
  ntf: JNotification;
  PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
  //Android 7.1
  service             : JService;
  serviceObjectId     : Pointer;
  ntf2                : JNotification;
  intent2             : JIntent;
  PendingIntent2      : JPendingIntent;

begin

   Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY;

   // can't ref .O on earlier phones, must hardcode
  if TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT > 26 then // JBuild_VERSION_CODES.JavaClass.O
  begin
     //Android 8.1
     //new ways for SDK > 26 (won't be called when API < 26 anyways)
      ServiceChannel := TJNotificationChannel.JavaClass.init(
      StringtoJString('com.radio.one'), //CHANNEL_ID
      StrToJCharSequence('Public radio Channel'),
      TJNotificationManager.JavaClass.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    );

    Obj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(
    TJContext.JavaClass.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationManager := TJNotificationManager.Wrap(Obj);
    NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(ServiceChannel);

    NewIntent:= TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName());
    NewIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
    NewIntent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    NewIntent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, NewIntent,
      TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    );

    ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(
      TAndroidHelper.Context,
      StringToJString('com.radio.one')
    );

   ncb.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('PublicRadio Service'));
   // ncb.setTicker(StrToJCharSequence('MyCommsService')); // can't remember why this is commented out to be honest
   ncb.setSmallIcon(JavaService.getApplicationInfo.icon);
   ncb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent);
   ncb.setOngoing(True);
   ntf := ncb.build;
   JavaService.startForeground(StartId, ntf);

 end
 else
 begin
      //Android 7.1
      serviceObjectId  := (JavaService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
      service          := TJService.Wrap(serviceObjectId);
      /////ntf2             := TJNotification.Create;
      ////ntf2.icon        := service.getApplicationInfo.icon;

    NewIntent:= TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName());
    NewIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
    NewIntent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    NewIntent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent2 := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(
      TAndroidHelper.Context, 0, NewIntent,
      TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    );

      ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(
      TAndroidHelper.Context,
      StringToJString('com.radio.one')
    );

      //intent2  := TJIntent.Create;
      //PendingIntent2 := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getActivity(service.getApplicationContext, 0, intent2, 0);

      ncb.setContentTitle(StrToJCharSequence('PublicRadio'));
      // ncb.setTicker(StrToJCharSequence('MyCommsService'));
      ncb.setSmallIcon(JavaService.getApplicationInfo.icon);
      ncb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent2);
      ncb.setOngoing(True);
      ntf2 := ncb.build;

      ntf2.setLatestEventInfo(service.getApplicationContext, StrToJCharSequence('PublicRadio'), StrToJCharSequence('PublicRadio Service'), PendingIntent2);
      service.startForeground(StartId, ntf2);
  end;

end;
```